# How can I change the file extension of files created by the VS Code Cpptools extension's "Create Declaration / Definition" feature?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

The VS Code Cpptools extension contributes a context menu item "Create Declaration / Definition" when right clicking a declaration in a header file.

Clicking that menu item/action causes the extension to create a source file whose extension is `.cpp`. However, I want it to be `.cc` not `.cpp`

I can't find the setting about file extension.

**Is there any way to make source file not `.cpp` but something else like `.cc` or `.cxx`?**

Version information

- VS Code: 1.78.2 (latest)
- C/C++ (Extension): v1.15.4

Comment: @rioV8 https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/blob/v1.15.4/Extension/package.nls.json#L34

Comment: I followed the path to [client.ts#L3524](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/blob/5ce976f322cf352f6ce7f0886aa195fca1b0164c/Extension/src/LanguageServer/client.ts#L3524), there it does some request and gets back info to create a `modified` file uri to apply some edits to. I could not find who does accepts the request, I can only find calls to `sendRequest`, found out you located the same file (in the issue)

Answer (score 0):

I started a GitHub discussion in the VS Code Cpptools repo to ask this [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/discussions/10969#discussioncomment-5943176).

The current answer is that **this is not currently possible** (source: [from the mouth of the maintainers](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/discussions/10969#discussioncomment-5943176)).

An issue ticket has been created for this feature-request at [Enable changing the file extension of files created when using the "Create Declaration / Definition"
#10970](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/10970). Since such a feature would require support from the server side of the extension, an issue ticket for that has been created at [C++ Create Declaration / Definition always uses .cpp/.h file extensions with no way to configure it](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/C-Create-Declaration--Definition-alwa/10368824).

I'm not aware of any workarounds (aside from manually renaming the file to change the file extension yourself after the new file is created).

I'll update this answer if/when the answer changes.

Answer (score -2):

1. Open the settings.
2. Click on the "Open Settings (JSON)" button located at the top-right corner. This will open the settings.json file.

```json
"files.associations": {
"*.cc": "cpp"
}
```

Comment: I don't think this answer the question here. The question here is about files created by using the "Create Declaration / Definition" button.

Comment: Well, It also make `.cpp` file to me. not `.cc`... I want to make `.cc` file with button "Create Declaration / Definition"