# How do I save a new c++ file with .cxx extension in vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I open a new editor tab, set the language mode to c++ and write some code. When I try to save it, vscode shows `<firstline>.cpp` as default. How to change the default name to `<firstline>.cxx` or any other extension?

There seems no option about this in vscode settings and C/C++ extension configurations.

Comment: go to File Explorer and use **New File** button and type file name with the extension you want

Comment: I just asked about this: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/discussions/10969#discussioncomment-6749714. I can write up an answer later with what I find from the maintainers' reply. also for your viewing pleasure during the wait: https://stackoverflow.com/q/76278014/11107541