# Can you modify template of "Create Definition" in VS Code for C++ to use namespace blocks instead of top-level, fully qualified definitions?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

Let's say I write a new class. I start with a header `MyClass.hpp`:

```
#pragma once

namespace MyProjectNamespace {
class MyClass {
public:
    foo(int i);
};
}
```

There is no corresponding .cpp file yet, but C++ extension has a nice Quick Fix to solve it - I can <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> and choose "Create definition of 'foo' in MyClass.cpp". This will create a `MyClass.cpp` file like this:

```
#include "MyClass.hpp"

MyProjectNamespace::MyClass::foo(int i)
{
}
```

However, as you can see, this uses (almost) fully qualified name in definition instead of opening a namespace like in a header. I can fix it myself and any further "Create definition" actions will place it correctly inside the namespace, but it's still a bit annoying on new files.

Is it possible to change the behaviour of this action with setting or somehow modify the template used by the extension to always open a namespace (if not present) on new definitions?

Comment: it would be at least ok if it is working like it does in eclipse. If you have no namespace blocks it will do as VSCode does. But if you add them it will notice them and set the functions correctly. additionally it will give you the possibility to select which functions to implement. 
If you try this in VSCode it will scramble up everything by placing the function with the full namespace somewhere right inside a namespace. That would never compile.
Would be glad to have a solution that works at list alike or better than in eclipse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not aware of there being any way for this to be configured by the user, nor am I aware of any [existing feature-request issue ticket](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues?q=is%3Aissue+label%3A%22Feature%3A+Create+Declaration+or+Definition%22+namespace). I'd suggest that if you want such a configuration feature to exist, then you should [create a feature-request issue ticket](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/new?assignees=&labels=&projects=&template=3_feature-request.yml) clearly defining the behaviour you'd like to have.

Side note: This question reminds me of [How can I change the file extension of files created by the VS Code Cpptools extension's "Create Declaration / Definition" feature?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76278014/11107541).

Comment: If anyone reading this ends up raising an issue ticket like I suggested, please either comment here with the link to it, or notify me in it with "@starball5" and a link to this Stack Overflow post so I can update it.